# passport-slack return Cannot GET /auth/slack

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, slack-api, slack

I'm developing an app that has slack signin functionality.

I'm using **passport-slack** for OAuth but having some problem about **routing** which return **Cannot GET /auth/slack**

I followed the step by step procedure which can be found in https://github.com/mjpearson/passport-slack but still no luck

My current code for passport is like this which I think I define the routes correctly

```
// setup the strategy using defaults
passport.use(new SlackStrategy({
  clientID: environment.SLACK.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: environment.SLACK.CLIENT_SECRET,
  }, (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
    done(null, profile);
}));

// path to start the OAuth flow
app.get('/auth/slack', passport.authenticate('slack'));

// OAuth callback url
app.get('/auth/slack/callback',
  passport.authenticate('slack', { successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login' }));
```

Comment: you didn't have the route `/auth/slack`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update my code since I just base it on documentation, still return same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/auth/slack` is just a middleware for authentication, which means all the routes begin with `/auth/slack` will invoke this middleware.

Also because you don have any `response` for this route, and passport will just invoke the `next()` function, so `Cannot GET /auth/slack`

You should put `/auth/slack/callback` in your slack settings, slack will redirect the user to this route after the user sign in on slack

http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: Thanks for explaining